# Reference in range for

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I studied that references always need to be initialzed.
So why this code reported as an example of range based for, in my C++ book, should be correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()    
{
    vector <int> v {0, 1, 2, 3}    // should double each element of v,
                                   // without writing it.
    for (auto &r : v) 
    {
       r *= 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for all your answers, I know you're all skillful programmers...
But some answers are still too advanced for me, so I'll choose the most intelligible for me. Thanks, again!

Comment: The semantics of the range-based `for` dictate that the `auto& r` will be re-created each time through the loop and initialized each time to reference the next element in `v`. i.e. it's still being initialized, but the initialization is implicit.

Comment: More succinctly, the behavior of that loop is equivalent to `for (vector<int>::iterator r = v.begin(); r != v.end(); r++)`

Comment: @Namfuak almost equivalent, the `r` is already dereferenced and the `v.end()` is not called each go-around and it's more `++r` than `r++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference is initialised in each iteration, to refer to each element of the vector.

This style of for-loop is roughly equivalent to one like

```
for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    auto &r = *it;
    // your code goes here
}
```

where you can see that the reference is initialised.

Another answer quotes the full definition from the language standard, if you're interested in the gory details.

Comment: As far as I know of C++, this is the most useful alternative example of range-based for statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the semantic description of the range based for statement there is written

```
for-range-declaration = *__begin;
```

Relative to your example this equivalent to

```
auto &r = *__begin;
```

that is that reference is always initialized.

Here is the complete semantic definition of the range fased for statement from the C++ Standard

```
{
    auto && __range = range-init;
    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
          __end = end-expr;
          __begin != __end;
          ++__begin ) {
          for-range-declaration = *__begin;
          statement
    }
}
```

That is this statement

```
for ( for-range-declaration : expression ) statement
```

is semantically equivalent to the construction above.

For example if *expression* is an array named a with N elements then the loop will look like

```
for ( auto __begin = a, __end = a + N; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) 
{
    auto &r = *__begin;
    //...
}
```

Comment: What you mean with *_begin?

Comment: Still don't get it, are end and begin functions? Why are they without the final parenthesis? And what's that underscore _ in the start?

Comment: @Calogero Napoli It depends on the type of expression. If it is an array for example named A then begin is A and end is A + N where N is the number of elements in the array. If it is a class then the compiler searches names begin and end for this class in its scope and if there are member functions with such names it uses them.

Comment: @@Calogero Napoli  See also an example in my post.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think you can just use `std::end` to get to the end, it should be overloaded for static arrays

Comment: @PeterT: We can; but the question is about a range-based for loop, which is specified to find the end of an array using pointer arithmetic, not `std::end` (although that would do the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

I always like to think of

```
for (auto &r : v)
{
    ...
}
```

as equivalent to

```
std::for_each(std::begin(v),std::end(v),[&](auto &r)
{
    ...
});
```

note that the `auto &r`  in the lambda needs C++14.

**edit:** or mixing the definition in the standard from @VladfromMoscow and the answer from @JBL

```
    for(
      auto it = std::begin(v),
      end = std::end(v); 
      it != end;
      ++it)
    {
        auto& r = *it;
        //Loop code
    }
```

Maybe that is easier for you to grasp than the description in the standard (although it's not as precise as the description in the standard).

Comment: Sorry, it's quite unreadable for me... What's that for_each? There is some missed and more parenthesis...

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli huh, where did I miss paranthesis?

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli: No there aren't.

Comment: @PeterT What's this }); ?

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli I'm sorry, if you're not familiar with the lambda syntax or the algortihm funcions then I don't think my first example is helpful to you, just look at the other example I provided

Answer (score 0):

Because the semantics of the range-based for loop are roughly equivalent to the following (readable) code:

```
auto it = v.begin();
for(; it != v.end(); ++it){
    auto& r = *it;
    //Loop code
}
```

That is, the reference is declared and initialized it each time.

Comment: I would put a `auto end = v.end();` before the loop and then make it `for(; it != end; ++it){` since it's not called on each iteration like it would in your code

Answer (score 0):

The `auto& r` component is not meant to represent an entire declaration; it only specifies the type and name of the element to generate on each iteration.

The initialisation is handled for you at the start of each iteration by the innards of range-for. That's the point! :)

Similarly, in the following, you do not assign values to `x` on your own; it's done by the loop:

```
for (int x : v) {}
```